# How to restore previous android id from titanium backup?

Tags: titanium-backup

My line apps doesn't work because it counts on android id.

I want to restore my android id then. However, out of so many back up files in titanium back up, which one contains my old id?

Answer (score 6):

Android ID can be found in the database *settings.db* of Settings Storage/Providers app. It is located under */data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases*.

There are multiple ways of restoring Android ID.

## Through Titanium Backup

In Titanium Backup (TiBu), go to Menu → Manage Android ID → Restore Android ID from a backup. **If one or multiple backups of Settings Storage/Providers app exists** then TiBu would list the ID. You can then select the ID and begin restoration of it.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

However, if no such backup of that app exists, then you would get this dialog:

[image: IMG:]

## Using command-line

If you already know which ID has to be restored then you can do this:

Setup [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) in PC and execute:

[image: IMG]

<sub>(The lines starting with *echo* are only for the purpose of explaining what I'm going to do in consecutive command. Avoid executing them.)</sub>

You can also edit *settings.db* using an SQLite database manager such as [sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/), but why bother this much?

---

Interestingly, the hostname of your device would be nothing more than *android-ANDROID_ID* where *ANDROID_ID* is the Android ID. You can check it using:

```
adb shell getprop net.hostname
```

**Note**: the whole solution is tested on Android 4.2.1 and 6.0.1.

Comment: Forgot to mention that you must restart the device after changing the ID.

Comment: There's no "Manage Android ID" option in Titanium Backup menu

Comment: @QkiZ I don't know about the recent version. Back when I had posted this answer it was available.